# User-Defined Functions SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, user-defined-functions

Performance Tuning Poor inherit UDF in SQL Server.

Recently I've acquired a new SQL Server environment. I've been able to make different parts faster put I'm having trouble with this one table-value function that calls on two scalar-value functions. The problem is Performance Tuning UDF is one of something I'm pretty new at and I would like some help as to how I could make this faster.

I understand Scalar-value Functions are used for row-by-row processing. So I'm looking for a way to make this faster. Can someone please help. Below are the functions.

Scalar-valued Functions 1. Adding this just to show whats going on.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AgingFactorOverride]
    (@Aging_Factor FLOAT, 
     @Company_ID INT, 
     @Survey_ID INT, 
     @Country_Code VARCHAR(50), 
     @Effective_Date DATETIME)
RETURNS FLOAT
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RetVal FLOAT

    BEGIN
        SELECT @RetVal = MAX(Aging_Factor) 
        FROM companysurveycountryaging csca 
        WHERE csca.company_id = @Company_ID 
          AND csca.Country_Code = @Country_Code 
          AND ISNULL(csca.survey_id, '') = CASE WHEN csca.survey_id IS NOT NULL
                                                   THEN @Survey_ID 
                                                   ELSE '' 
                                           END
          AND csca.effective_date = (SELECT MAX(cscaa.effective_date) 
                                     FROM companysurveycountryaging cscaa 
                                     WHERE cscaa.company_id = @Company_ID 
                                       AND cscaa.Country_Code = @Country_Code    
                                       AND ISNULL(cscaa.survey_id, '') = CASE WHEN cscaa.survey_id IS NOT NULL THEN @Survey_ID ELSE '' END 
                                       AND cscaa.effective_date <= @Effective_Date)

        IF @RetVal IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @RetVal = @Aging_Factor
        END
    END

    RETURN @RetVal
END
```

Scalar-value Function 2.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AgeData]
(@ValToAge float, @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime, @AgingFactor float)
RETURNS float
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
Declare @RetVal float,@NumMonths float

if @AgingFactor is not NULL
  Begin
    Set @NumMonths=DateDiff(month,@StartDate,@EndDate);
    Set @RetVal=@ValToAge*(1+(((@AgingFactor/12)*@NumMonths)/100));
  End
else
  set @RetVal=@ValToAge;
Return @RetVal
END
```

Table-valued Function -- Here is a sample of the query that calling on the above scalar function.

```
Select
@Base25=ISNULL(dbo.AgeData(sd.base25,s.effective_Date,@Effective_Date,dbo.AgingFactorOverride(cs.aging_factor,@Company_ID,sd.Survey_ID,sd.Country_Code,@Effective_Date)),0),
@Base50=ISNULL(dbo.AgeData(sd.base50,s.effective_Date,@Effective_Date,dbo.AgingFactorOverride(cs.aging_factor,@Company_ID,sd.Survey_ID,sd.Country_Code,@Effective_Date)),0),
@Base75=ISNULL(dbo.AgeData(sd.base75,s.effective_Date,@Effective_Date,dbo.AgingFactorOverride(cs.aging_factor,@Company_ID,sd.Survey_ID,sd.Country_Code,@Effective_Date)),0),
@BaseAVG=ISNULL(dbo.AgeData(sd.baseAVG,s.effective_Date,@Effective_Date,dbo.AgingFactorOverride(cs.aging_factor,@Company_ID,sd.Survey_ID,sd.Country_Code,@Effective_Date)),0),
@TCC25=ISNULL(dbo.AgeData(sd.TCC25,s.effective_Date,@Effective_Date,dbo.AgingFactorOverride(cs.aging_factor,@Company_ID,sd.Survey_ID,sd.Country_Code,@Effective_Date)),0),
@TCC50=ISNULL(dbo.AgeData(sd.TCC50,s.effective_Date,@Effective_Date,dbo.AgingFactorOverride(cs.aging_factor,@Company_ID,sd.Survey_ID,sd.Country_Code,@Effective_Date)),0),
@TCC75=ISNULL(dbo.AgeData(sd.TCC75,s.effective_Date,@Effective_Date,dbo.AgingFactorOverride(cs.aging_factor,@Company_ID,sd.Survey_ID,sd.Country_Code,@Effective_Date)),0),
@TCCAVG=ISNULL(dbo.AgeData(sd.TCCAVG,s.effective_Date,@Effective_Date,dbo.AgingFactorOverride(cs.aging_factor,@Company_ID,sd.Survey_ID,sd.Country_Code,@Effective_Date)),0),
@Base10=ISNULL(dbo.AgeData(sd.Base10,s.effective_Date,@Effective_Date,dbo.AgingFactorOverride(cs.aging_factor,@Company_ID,sd.Survey_ID,sd.Country_Code,@Effective_Date)),0),
@Base90=ISNULL(dbo.AgeData(sd.Base90,s.effective_Date,@Effective_Date,dbo.AgingFactorOverride(cs.aging_factor,@Company_ID,sd.Survey_ID,sd.Country_Code,@Effective_Date)),0),
from surveydata sd, surveys s,companysurveys cs
where cs.company_id=s.Company_ID and cs.survey_id=s.survey_id and s.survey_id=sd.survey_id
```

Please let me know if you need anything else to make this work better.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read how to ask section for asking better questions. Thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe it ain't broke, in which case don't fix it.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Change the scalar function to inline table valued function

```
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Agingfactoroverride] (@Aging_Factor   FLOAT,
                                            @Company_ID     INT,
                                            @Survey_ID      INT,
                                            @Country_Code   VARCHAR(50),
                                            @Effective_Date DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
    RETURN
      (SELECT Isnull((SELECT Max(Aging_Factor)
                      FROM   (SELECT Rnk = Dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY effective_date DESC),
                                     Aging_Factor
                              FROM   companysurveycountryaging csca
                              WHERE  csca.company_id = @Company_ID
                                     AND csca.Country_Code = @Country_Code
                                     AND (csca.survey_id = @Survey_ID or csca.survey_id is null)
                                     AND csca.effective_date <= @Effective_Date) a
                      WHERE  Rnk = 1), @Aging_Factor))

GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Agedata] (@ValToAge    FLOAT,
                                @StartDate   DATETIME,
                                @EndDate     DATETIME,
                                @AgingFactor FLOAT)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
    RETURN
      (SELECT CASE
                WHEN @AgingFactor IS NOT NULL THEN @ValToAge * ( 1 + ( ( ( @AgingFactor / 12 ) * Datediff(month, @StartDate, @EndDate) ) / 100 ) )
                ELSE @ValToAge
              END);
```

Use `outer apply` to call the functions

```
SELECT Base25,
       Base50,
       Base75,
       BaseAVG,
       TCC25,
       TCC50,
       TCC75,
       TCCAVG,
       Base10,
       Base90
FROM   surveydata sd
       INNER JOIN surveys s
               ON s.survey_id = sd.survey_id
       INNER JOIN companysurveys cs
               ON cs.company_id = s.Company_ID
                  AND cs.survey_id = s.survey_id
       OUTER apply (SELECT Base25 = Isnull(dbo.Agedata(sd.base25, s.effective_Date, @Effective_Date, dbo.Agingfactoroverride(cs.aging_factor, @Company_ID, sd.Survey_ID, sd.Country_Code, @Effective_Date)), 0),
                           Base50 = Isnull(dbo.Agedata(sd.base50, s.effective_Date, @Effective_Date, dbo.Agingfactoroverride(cs.aging_factor, @Company_ID, sd.Survey_ID, sd.Country_Code, @Effective_Date)), 0),
                           Base75 = Isnull(dbo.Agedata(sd.base75, s.effective_Date, @Effective_Date, dbo.Agingfactoroverride(cs.aging_factor, @Company_ID, sd.Survey_ID, sd.Country_Code, @Effective_Date)), 0),
                           BaseAVG = Isnull(dbo.Agedata(sd.baseAVG, s.effective_Date, @Effective_Date, dbo.Agingfactoroverride(cs.aging_factor, @Company_ID, sd.Survey_ID, sd.Country_Code, @Effective_Date)), 0),
                           TCC25 = Isnull(dbo.Agedata(sd.TCC25, s.effective_Date, @Effective_Date, dbo.Agingfactoroverride(cs.aging_factor, @Company_ID, sd.Survey_ID, sd.Country_Code, @Effective_Date)), 0),
                           TCC50 = Isnull(dbo.Agedata(sd.TCC50, s.effective_Date, @Effective_Date, dbo.Agingfactoroverride(cs.aging_factor, @Company_ID, sd.Survey_ID, sd.Country_Code, @Effective_Date)), 0),
                           TCC75 = Isnull(dbo.Agedata(sd.TCC75, s.effective_Date, @Effective_Date, dbo.Agingfactoroverride(cs.aging_factor, @Company_ID, sd.Survey_ID, sd.Country_Code, @Effective_Date)), 0),
                           TCCAVG = Isnull(dbo.Agedata(sd.TCCAVG, s.effective_Date, @Effective_Date, dbo.Agingfactoroverride(cs.aging_factor, @Company_ID, sd.Survey_ID, sd.Country_Code, @Effective_Date)), 0),
                           Base10 = Isnull(dbo.Agedata(sd.Base10, s.effective_Date, @Effective_Date, dbo.Agingfactoroverride(cs.aging_factor, @Company_ID, sd.Survey_ID, sd.Country_Code, @Effective_Date)), 0),
                           Base90 = Isnull(dbo.Agedata(sd.Base90, s.effective_Date, @Effective_Date, dbo.Agingfactoroverride(cs.aging_factor, @Company_ID, sd.Survey_ID, sd.Country_Code, @Effective_Date)), 0)) oa
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will test and verify this is going to be better. Thanks again.